# iptables rule to allow all traffic from INPUT and source 10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0

Tags: iptables

Whats the `iptables` rule/command to allow all traffic from INPUT and source 10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0, i.e. anything either UDP or TCP? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

if you need only TCP and UDP